# Wide negative vote numbers don't fit well in related questions vote boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/213/snapshot1xo.png](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39989/dont-allow-for-a-question-to-be-marked-dupe-if-the-dupe-doesnt-show-up-under-r)

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome, not confirmed in FF -- the latter keeps them in one line.

Comment: Chrome is a fine browser.

Comment: Your ability to multitask scares me.

Comment: @Georg: and you haven't seen the other 3 desktops with 4 windows each ;) Also, http://xkcd.com/214/

Comment: No-repro in WinXP + FF 3.6

Comment: @Georg I was going to make a similar comment. Too funny.

Comment: Confirmed to affect Chrome 4.1.249.1045 (Webkit) and Internet Explorer 7.0.5730.13 (Trident), but works as expected in FireFox 3.5.9 (Gecko) and Opera 9.62 (Presto). All Windows XP builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made this use the [same code path as the user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/small-layout-glitch-on-user-home-page-if-an-answer-has-over-1k-votes-closed) when rendering those styles.